# Parse a multiline string in JAVA that includes spaces in between

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to parse the following **block of string** that has *four* spaces before and between keys, datatype and values:

```
    PYTHON_HOME    REG_SZ    C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts
    PYTHON_PATH    REG_SZ    C:\tsde\Python\v34
    SCALA_HOME    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files (x86)\scala
    SZ    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\7-Zip
    TEMP    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
    TMP    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

I would like to parse the string and assign parsed values to variables or a multi-dimensional array. The expected result that I am looking for is something like:

```
Key1 = PYTHON_HOME, Value1 = C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts

Key2 = SCALA_HOME, Value2 = C:\Program Files (x86)\scala

Key3 = SZ, Value3 = C:\Program Files\7-Zip

Key4 =TEMP, Value4 = %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp

Key5 = TMP, Value5 = %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

So far I have been playing with pattern and matcher in java.util.regex and haven't actually gotten anywhere.

Please note that the given block of string may have more lines of keys, dataType and values.

Comment: Wouldn't some thing like `String[] parts = input.split("    ");` work better?

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I think he has to use `DOT_ALL` with `Pattern` class since his string is multiline

Comment: @TheLostMind Yeah, I'm thinking single line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(.*?)[ ]{4}.*?[ ]{4}(.*)$
```

You can simply use this and grab the captures or groups.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wX9fR1/26

```
String line = "test_string";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)[ ]{4}.*?[ ]{4}(.*)$",Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("group 1: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("group 2: " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

Comment: Since I've spent 10 minutes reading other tutorials and hacking out my solution, I can tell you, the link doesn't provide the information the OP is going to need to put it together. Yes, the regular expression works, but that's 10% of the work...If you prefer, I could post my own answer, with the code I've got working, using your expression...

Comment: @vks : I like the approach using the tool but how do I programatically do it and store into variables or an array?

Comment: @vks: This is what I get after running your code:

group 1: 
group 2: REG_SZ    C:\ffds\mule\servers\mule-standalone-3.5.2
group 1: 
group 2: REG_EXPAND_SZ    C:\cygwin64\bin;%PYTHON_HOME%;C:\Users\john.doe\Documents\Automation\libs;%MONGO_HOME%\bin

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I would like you see your solution since you mentioned you already have one

Comment: @summerNight It's pretty much the same as the one vks has posted ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer this should word.But i am not very proficient in java.Is there any error you can spot ?Coz OP is not getting the answer

Comment: @vks Not really.  This works for me, assuming that the data the OP has posted is correct and each line block is on a separate line - Certainly worked okay for me

Comment: @vks: Sorry I apologize. The lines had 4 spaces on the front as well. My editor was somehow preserving the formatting I guess. Your solutions works great for me after I added regex to detect the 4 spaces on the front "^[ ]{4}(.*?)[ ]{4}.*?[ ]{4}(.*)$" ... Thanks! I have updated my question on this post.

Answer (score 2):

This will also work :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String s = "PYTHON_HOME    REG_SZ    C:\\Python27;C:\\Python27\\Scripts\nPYTHON_PATH    REG_SZ    C:\\tsde\\Python\\v34\nSCALA_HOME    REG_SZ    C:\\Program Files (x86)\\scala\nSZ    REG_SZ    C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\nTEMP    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\nTMP    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Temp";
        System.out.println(s);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\n|^)(.*?)\\s+(.*?)\\s+(.*?)(?=\\n+|$)",
                Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        while (m.find()) {
            List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
            temp.add(m.group(1));
            temp.add(m.group(2));
            temp.add(m.group(3));
            list.add(temp);
        }

        for (List<String> ll : list) {
            System.out.println("1 : " + ll.get(0));
            System.out.println("2 : " + ll.get(1));
            System.out.println("3 : " + ll.get(2));
        }
    }
```

O/P :

```
PYTHON_HOME    REG_SZ    C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts
PYTHON_PATH    REG_SZ    C:\tsde\Python\v34
SCALA_HOME    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files (x86)\scala
SZ    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\7-Zip
TEMP    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
1 : PYTHON_HOME
2 : REG_SZ
3 : C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts
1 : PYTHON_PATH
2 : REG_SZ
3 : C:\tsde\Python\v34
1 : SCALA_HOME
2 : REG_SZ
3 : C:\Program Files (x86)\scala
1 : SZ
2 : REG_SZ
3 : C:\Program Files\7-Zip
1 : TEMP
2 : REG_EXPAND_SZ
3 : %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
1 : TMP
2 : REG_EXPAND_SZ
3 : %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Comment: This seems to assume that the `String` is a single line, what happens if its separated by new lines?

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I've added \n to make it multi line (on linux :P on windows \r\n should be used) . Check my String `s`

Comment: Yeah, got lost in the noise :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Couldn't keep it cleaner :(